# how to Check if User has arrived from Multiple Domains in HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php

I have a query

How to check if user has came to my main domain through multiple pages? i mean in my HTTP REFERER

```
<?php
$ref = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']: null ;

if($ref == 'http://www.site1.com' || $ref == 'http://www.site2.com') {

}
else
{
echo'<center><h1 style="color:red"><br/><br/>Sorry To Inform You Direct Access Is Not Allowed First Go To The Home Page <br/><br/><a href="http://mainsite.com">Click Here</a></h1></center>';
}

?>
```

this is the code i am currently using but it doesnt supposed to be working for me.. I want that first user visit site2.com then site1.com then only he get able to visit my site, or else if he try to come from site1.com directly, then page give him error that access not allowed..

Is it possible? if yes, how is it so? cuz i have a guy who have this working.. He also uses HTTP REFERER and he added this thing that user have to come from site2 to site1 and from site1 to his site, only then, user will see content, and if user tried coming directly from site1 to his site, he will see error that content not allowed.

Comment: Why should you block the user coming directly to your domain? This is out of usability and I don't see any proper reason for doing that. Very likely that you have an issue on your design-Or did I miss something important?

Comment: yes i want to block them.. Its important for me. Can you please check the code and tell if i did anything wrong?